# No site configured at this address

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, microsoft-edge

So I tried to go onto a site about a quarter ago, however it just said "No site configured at this address", so I went on to research, and found that most people said that if I cleared the cache, it should work again, and most of the questions, it seems that it's only 1 browser it doesn't work in, for me it's all of my browsers, clearing cache and clearing history did not help whatsoever in neither of the browsers. Could this be a problem with the website? Or is there something I have missed? The site worked well yesterday.

Comment: I have already tried that, didn't help either :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying to do some other stuff online, I ended up with a "The proxy server is refusing connections", so I realised that I had enabled a proxy, disabling this fixed the problem!

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem in your device, in your internet connection or in the server you're connecting to.

To know where is the problem, test it using this **[service](http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/)** called `down for every one or just me` where you can check if the site is really down or if it is only a problem on your side.

Comment: It says that it's just me

Comment: Can you ping it? You will need to ask  your ISP support if they are able to connect to it.

Comment: I solved it, just a proxy related issue